# How I can reset the collector timer everytime a message is collected?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I want to collect the messages from the user, but I'm having issues to implement that if the users stops typing for let's say 5 minutes the collector/command ends.

Currently I can have it run infinitely without the *time* and *max* filter, and I know I can check for a word like "stop" so the users can stop the command themselves, but I want to make sure so the collector/command stops itself if the users forgets to do so.

```js
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from "discord.js";
import { command, textToSpeech } from "../../utils";

const meta = new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("echo")
  .setDescription("I'll say in voice whatever you type.");

export default command(meta, ({ interaction }) => {
  if (!interaction.channel) {
    return interaction.reply(`You can't use this command here.`);
  }

  if (interaction.channel.type != 0) {
    return interaction.reply(`I can't read your messages here.`);
  }

  interaction.reply(`Now I'll say everything you type.`);

  const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({
    filter: (msg) => msg.author.id === interaction.user.id,
    max: 1,
    time: 300000,
  });

  collector.on("collect", (msg) => {
    textToSpeech(msg.content);
  });

  collector.on("end", () => {
    interaction.reply(`Now I'll stop saying what you type.`);
  });
});
```

Also I'm having issues sending another reply on **collector.on("end")** as it seems an interaction can only be replied once. How would I send a reply at the end? as if I edit the first reply the user may not see it due to the reply message going up as users type.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by removing the *max* filter, and resetting the timer with **collector.resetTimer();** on the *collector.on("collect", ...)*

Also, I am able to send another reply using **interaction.followUp()** to send another reply when the collector ends.

here the solution code:

```js
  const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({
    filter: (msg) => msg.author.id === interaction.user.id,
    time: 300000,
  });

  collector.on("collect", (msg) => {
    textToSpeech(msg.content);
    collector.resetTimer();
  });

  collector.on("end", () => {
    interaction.followUp(`Now I'll stop saying what you type.`);
  });
```